# Get second last value in each row of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, tail

I am trying to get the second last value in each row of a data frame, meaning the first job a person has had. (Job1_latest is the most recent job and people had a different number of jobs in the past and I want to get the first one). I managed to get the last value per row with the code below:

first_job <- function(x)   tail(x[!is.na(x)], 1)

first_job <- apply(data, 1, first_job)

```
structure(list(Index = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59), 
    FromJob = c("Senior Machine Learning Engineer", "Senior Machine Learning Engineer", 
    "Senior Machine Learning Engineer", "Senior Machine Learning Engineer", 
    "Senior Machine Learning Engineer", "Python Data Engineer (m/w/d)", 
    "Python Data Engineer (m/w/d)", "Python Data Engineer (m/w/d)", 
    "Lead Backend Developer (f/m/d)", "Lead Backend Developer (f/m/d)", 
    "Lead Backend Developer (f/m/d)", "Lead Backend Developer (f/m/d)", 
    "Python Data Engineer (m/w/d)", "Python Data Engineer (m/w/d)", 
    "Lead Developer", "Lead Developer", "Lead Developer", "Lead Developer", 
    "Lead Developer", "Lead Developer", "Team Lead Software Development", 
    "(Senior) Frontend Engineer", "(Senior) Frontend Engineer", 
    "(Senior) Frontend Engineer", "(Senior) Frontend Engineer", 
    "(Senior) Frontend Engineer", "(Senior) Frontend Engineer", 
    "Data Scientist", "Data Scientist", "Senior Backend (Java) Engineer", 
    "Senior Backend (Java) Engineer", "Senior Backend (Java) Engineer", 
    "Lead Developer", "Mobile Software Engineer", "Mobile Software Engineer", 
    "Mobile Software Engineer", "Mobile Software Engineer", "Mobile Software Engineer", 
    "Mobile Software Engineer", "Mobile Software Engineer", "Mobile Software Engineer", 
    "Mobile Software Engineer", "Mobile Software Engineer", "Mobile Software Engineer", 
    "Mobile Software Engineer", "Lead UI/UX Designer", "Lead UI/UX Designer", 
    "Lead UI/UX Designer", "Lead UI/UX Designer", "Head of Software Development", 
    "Head of Software Development", "Head of Software Development", 
    "Head of Software Development", "Head of Software Development", 
    "Head of Software Development", "Head of Software Development", 
    "Head of Software Development", "Jnuior Fullstack Developer", 
    NA), Highest_education_achieved = c("PhD", "MSc Computer Science", 
    "MSc", "MBA", "MSc", "MSc", "MSc", "MSc Communication and Media Engineering", 
    "High School", "BSc Informatics", "BSc Software engineering", 
    NA, "MSc in Electronic Engineering", "MSc in Communication and Media Engineering", 
    "BSc in Computer Engineering", "BSc in Technology", "MSc in Computer Science", 
    "BSc in Automatic Control System", "Dipl. Wirtschaftsinformatik", 
    "MCs Computer Science", "Dipl. Ing. in Software Development - Economics", 
    "MSc in Computer Science", "BSc. in Information Technology", 
    "MSc in Big Data and Business Analyst", "MSc. in Computer Science", 
    "Dipl.", "BSc.", "MSc. in Scientific Computing and Biomechanics", 
    "MSc. in Computational Engineering", "MSc. in Information Technology", 
    "MSc. in Computer Science", "MSc. in Informatics", "BSc.", 
    "BSc.", "BSc.", "BSc.", "BSc.", "BSc.", "BSc.", "BSc.", "Highschool", 
    "BSc.", "BSc.", "Highschool", "BSc.", "MCs.", "BSc.", "BSc.", 
    "BSc.", "MCs.", "BSc.", "Dipl.", "BSc.", "BSc.", "BSc.", 
    "BSc.", "MSc.", "BSc.", NA), Skills = c("Machine Learning, Mathematical Modeling, Scientific Computing, Linux, python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, keras, pandas, javascript, react.js, AWS, Lambda, EMR, EC2, S3, Glue, CloudFormation, git,  Image recognition, deep learning, Natural language processing, Big data integration, cloud migration, Azure, Fortran, OpenFOAM, mercurial", 
    "Java, AngularJS, frontend, backend, Azure, data collection, modelbuilding, evaluation, deployment, serving and computing online metrics,  Apache Spark, AWS Sagemaker, Airflow, MLflow, MLOps", 
    "Biometrics, Machine Learning, Pattern Recognition, AI, scrum, matlab, C++, Azure, logistics", 
    "Databricks, Spark, Airflow, AWS Sagemaker, Other AWS Services, Docker, Microstrategy, Presto, Python, PL/SQL, JavaScript, Shell Scripting, BigQuery (Google), Hadoop, Exasol, Kafka", 
    "Spark, Tensorflow &TFX, Kubeflow, BigQuery, Apache Beam (Dataflow), Google Cloud Platform", 
    "PythonC++, C, OpenCV, OpenCL, MatLab, TensorFlow/PyTorch, Caffe/Keras, Scikit-learn, Pandas/NumPy, Seaborn/Matplotlib, NLTK/spaCy, Computer Vision, Machine Learning, NLP, Linear/LogisticRegression, Naive Bayes/PCA, SVM/K Means, RandomForest, CNN/LSTM/GRU, Reinforcement Learning", 
    "Microsoft SQL Server, Hadoop,SQL Server Management Studio, VisualStudio(DataTools), PyCharm, Sublime text 3, SSIS, python, C#, \nC++, Html/Css, Java,T-SQL, git", 
    "Keras, TensorFlow, scikit-learn, NLTK, OpenCV, NumPy, pandas,Python, Java, PHP, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Angular, React, jQuery, Bootstrap, Flask, SQL, MongoDB, Git, Docker", 
    "ElasticSearch, OOP, NoSQL, SQL, Docker, Kibana, Git, Unittest, Openshift", 
    "PHP, Java Script, CSS, (X)HTML, MySQL., NodeJS", "JavaScript (Vue.js, React, jQuery), Node.js (Express), PHP (Yii, Laravel, Symfony), JAVA (Spring Boot), .NET C#, SQL(postregsql, mysql), Elastic, MongoDB, HTML + CSS, Sketch, InVision Studio", 
    NA, "Python, C++, HTML/CSS, Java, C#, T-SQL, Microsoft SQL Server, Hadoop, Pycharm, Sublimetext 3, SISS, Git,Liquid Planner,", 
    "Keras, TensorFlow, scikit-Learn, NLTK, openCV, NumPy, pandas, Python, Java, PHP, HTML, JavaScript,CSS, Angular, React, jQuery, Bootstrap, Flask, SQL, MonoDB, Git, Android, PhoneGap, Docker", 
    "Java, PL/SQL, HTML, JavaScript, PHP, Bash, AngularJs, ReactJs, Python, Weblogic, Jboss, Tomcat, Jetty, Apache, IIS, Unix, Windows, Oracle 8i, 9i, 10g, MySql, MariaDB, PostgrwSql, MS Sql Server, GIT, Mercury, Jira", 
    "JavaScript, AngularJs, Angular Next, jQuery, RequireJS, React, WebPack, Typescript, Node, PWA, Socket Programming, Kong,", 
    "GIT, SME, API's, iOS, UI, Mobile application, SVN, Epic, Apple, SAML,", 
    "Kotlin, Java, JavaScript, Typescript, Pytion ML, AI, Spring, NoSQL, SQL, Microservices, AWS, Azure, Angular9, React, Kafka, Jenkins, Cloud, Rancher, K8s, Cloud foundry, MSSQL, Elas, Tensorflow, Boot, Teras, Hibernite, RabbitMQ, JUnit, AWS SQS, Docker, C++, STL, XML, Linux, Bash,", 
    "Scrum, Code Reviews, JIRA, Mantis, Kanban, Trello, Java, Kotlin, Typescript, Groovy, JavaScript, Delphi, Openshift, Kubernetes, Docker, Azure, Open Telekom Cloud, CosmosDB, Heroku, REST, SOAP, XMPP, NATS, JMS, ActiveMQ, Gatling, Mocktesting, Mockito, EasyMock, Cucumber, Angular 8, React, GWT, JSF, JSP, Struts, Spring Boot, JEE, Hibernate, JPA, MongoDB, Oracle, Postgres, CosmosDB, MySQL, DB2, SQL-Tuning, Maven, Ant, Gradle, GIT, SVN, CVS, BIRT, JasperReports, MicroStrategy, Maven,", 
    "Kotlin, Java 11, Docker, AWS, GCP, Kubernetes,Neo-4j, Solr, Spring-boot, Postgres, Hibernate, Flyway, sendGrit, Gradl, rxJava, Freemaker, Grafana, Prometheus,Oauth 2, Spring-gateway, Microservices, AWS, Amazon EMR, DynamoDB, S3, Hive, hdfs, storm, kafka, reactive programming, spring-cloud, groovy, elasticsearch, hystrix, ribbon, eureka, API, java 8, grunt, bamboo, jenkins, JavaScript, Junit, jbpm, jmx, C++, j2ee, servlet,", 
    "Scrum, SAP, NetWeaver 7.40", "CSS. Html, Bootstrap, Php, MySQL, JavaScript, Wordpress, Typo 3, Google Analytics, Google Adwords, React, GatsbyJS, Nextjs, Flutter, Postgres, AWS, Docker, Google Cloud Platform,", 
    "Node JS, JavaScript, ES6, CSS, PHP, XML, JQuery, Lambda, Appsync, React, JS, HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap, REST web services, Microservices, JSON, Elasticsearch, Java, React JS, AWS Server, MAMP, Maven, Laravel, Codeigniter, MySQL, Dynamo DB, SQLite, Oracle, MS SQL, MAC, UNIX, Windows, Git, AWS-EC2, S3, Cloud Formation, Cloudwatch, SNS, PhpStorm, WebSorm, Visual Studio Code, Eclipse, Netbeans, Android Studio", 
    "C, C++, Java, J2EE, Dotnet, Angular, React, JS, JavaScript, Query, CSS, HTML, Microsoft SQL Server, GIT, React JS with Redux, Vue JS, CSS3, Bootstrap, Media query, AEM, Jest test, Python, Tabeleau, AWS, Miro", 
    "JavaScript, ReactJs, TypeScript, Python, C++, HTML, ASP, C#", 
    "SPA, TypeScript, React Hooks, Jest, Lerna, React Query, Azure DevOps, Storybook, RxJx, Socket.io, OpenAPI, SCSS,", 
    "JavaScript, React JS, Flow, Redux, React SSR, urql graphql client, Java 11, HTML5, CSSS3, JavaScript (ES6+), TypeScript, jQuery, AJAX, webpack, NodeJS, PHP, Express, MongoDB, SASS, Heroku, Linux, Hetzner, Git, AngularJS,", 
    "Linux, Windows, MS Office, Libre office, Python, SQL, Bash, C/C++, MATLAB, NumPy, SciPy, pandas, SciKit-Learn, statsmodels, Keras, TensorFlow, Flask, Matplotlib, Seaborn, Tableau, ParaView, Tecplot, Inkscape, GIMP, PyCharm, jupyter, Eclipse, Visual Studio, Git, Docker, Poetry, Pytest, Unittest, Pylint, Pre-commit", 
    "Python, C/C++, SQL, MySQL, Numpy, Pandas, Scipy, Scikit-Learn, Keras, Tensorflow, Theano, PyTorch, Visual Studio, Pycharm, Jupyter Notebook, Vscode, PowerBi, MS Office, Sourcetree, Jira, Git, Linux, Mac, Windows", 
    "NPM, Webpack, Bower, Gruntjs, Gulp, JavaScript, Angular, CSS, Animation, Angular-animation, TypeScript, ReactJS, Node.js, Lombok, Vue.js, Visual Studio, HTML, Maven, Redux, Chart.js, Kotlin,", 
    "Java. Web Services, Design Patterns, Agile Methodologies, Spring Hibernate, JSF, JUnit, Maven Eclipse, SQL, XML, Linux, Websphere, Tomcat, jQuery, Ant, JDBC, Subversion, JavaScript, CSS, JPA, Git, Jenkins, REST, services, AJAX, Glassfish, Java Enterprise Edition, Apache, Lucene, Artifactory,", 
    "Java, HTML, Perl, Programming, SQL, JavaScript, CSS, Oracle, C++, Linux, CSS, PHP, C#, Ruby, C", 
    NA, "Jira, Git, Scrum, Agile, Retrofit, Picasso, Volley, RESTful, HTTP, JSON, Asyns-task, Dagger2, MVVM Architecture, API, SQLite, Pandas, NumPy,", 
    "Kotlin, MVVM Archtiecture, Firebase, Google-Services, Git, Retrofit, JSON, Material Design UI, Constrains Layout Animations, Jira, Figma, Zeplin, Agile, Scrum", 
    "C++, Java, MVC Design, AdMob, Google Maps API Keys, Retrofit, Gson, SQLite, Picasso, Google Vision, Play Services, SQL, iOS Develpment, JSON, C#, XML, Android", 
    "Server-Side, Client-Side, NOSQL, Agile Development, Machine Learning, Elastic Search, AWS, C#, OOP, Object Oriented, Programming, SQL, DB, RDBMS, Relational Database, CSS, Angular, AngularJs, JavaScript, TypeScript, JQuery, HTML, PHP, .NET, MVC.NET, DOT.NET, HADOOP, Java, Apache Hive, XML, JSON, AJAX,MySQL, Visual Studio, Bootstrap, XCode, Android, IOS,", 
    "Kotlin, Java, Rx, Dagger, Retrofit, Data Binding, Glide, Picasso, Leak Canary,Git, Flow, MVP, MVVM, Junit, Mockito, Espresso, Repository, Pattern, Singleton Pattern, CI/CD, Python, C/C++, C#, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, React, Spring Boot, Slack, XML, Android Arch Components, Material Design, Timber, ML, Kit,", 
    "Android SDK, Java, Kotlin, XML, Firebase, Android Studio, GIMP, Illustrator, PHP, API,", 
    "Android Development, Java, Firebase, Kotlin, SQLite, Android Studio, SDK Implementation, Mobile Application, Version Control, JSON, IMA SDK, Google AdSense,  Jira, C#, Swift", 
    "Java, Android SDK, Java SE, GWT, AWT, SWT, JSP, JSTL, JSF, Hibernate, Struts, Kotlin, Swift, JavaScript, jQuery, Oracle, MySQL, SQLite, PHP, HTML, CSS, C#,GWT, Angular, Bootstrap, Junit, Selenium, Appium, JavaServer Faces, Zend, Eclipse, XCode, Unity, iOS, Firebase, Open Source, Atlassian, Apache, Microsoft, Adobe,", 
    "Android, Kotlin, Java, Dart, MVVM, UAT, CI/CD, UI/UX,", 
    "GoF Design Patterns, SOLID, MVVM, MVP, MVC, Android Development, AppoloGraphQL, Dagger2, RxJava, Jetpack Components, Kotlin, iOS, Swift, Autolayout, Python, JavaScript", 
    "Git, Youtrack, Trello, Jira, CI/CD, Gitlab, Teamcity, Kotlin, Java, Retrofit, Ktor, Android Architechture Compor Room, SQLDelight, RxJava2, Coroutines/Flow, MVP, MVVM, MVI, Python, Scrum, Waterfall", 
    "Java, Kotlin, XML, Android SDK, Retrofit, Okhttp, Dagger 2, Eventbus, Multithreating, Design Patterns, RX, Coroutines, Picasso, Glide, MVM, MVVM, MVP, Clean Architecture, Android Jetpack, Android Architecture Component, Espresso, Junit, Mockito, Cucumber, SQLite, Realm, Room, Firebase, Git", 
    "invison, Uxpin, Sketch, Figma, Slack Abstract, Adobe XD, Adobe InDesign, Illustrator, Adobe Photoshop, Adobe Muse, Rhinoceros, Animation Studio, MacOS, Microsoft Office, Material Design, Fluent Design, Swift, React, Angular, HTML, CSS, JS, GitHub", 
    "PHP, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, React, Python, CRO,  Adobe XD, Sketch, InVision, Lingo App, TripleTex,", 
    "Figma, Sketch, Invision, Adobe XD, Adobe Creative Cloud, Craft Marvel,", 
    "Figma, Sketch, Photoshop, Illustrator, Adobe After Effects, Maya, Cinema 4D, JavaScript, HTML, CSS, React, Node, Next.js, TailwindCSS, Firebase, MongoDB,", 
    "Java, C#.NET, PHP, Python, JavaScript, HTML, CSS, XML, Datenbanken, SQL, Geodaten, CMS Systeme, Jira, Confluence, Linux, Webserver-Betrieb, Catching, Load Balancing, Monitoring CI Systeme, automatisiertes Testen, Deployment,", 
    "Software Engineering, DevOps, System Architecture, Agile Transformation, IT Security, Python, Java, CI, CD, Docker, iOS, C++, C#, Golang, Ruby, Node JS, PostgrSQL, MySQL, RethinkDB, Cassandra, Consul", 
    "Cobol, Delta, ISAM, Java, JavaScript, CSS, Eclipse RCP, ANTLR, JPA, Maven, JPA/Hibernate, Lucene, HSQL, Oracle, Tomcat, Jetty, Axis, JBoss, JAX-WS, SOAP, WSDL, HBase, Jenkins, SNS, S3, SASS, Jira, Github, SEO/SM, Gitlab, Kotlin, Kafka,", 
    "AWS, Azure, Angular, MongoDB, Node.js, iOS,", "Java, RIM, COM Interfaces, Edifact, MT940, XSLT, XML, Tomcat, JMS, Arvo Workflowsystem, XSL-FO, Xalan, JSP, Servlets, JavaScript, Struts, EJB, JPA, Trinidad, Drools, XFire, Eclipse, Springframework, Dozer Framework,", 
    "Android, Java, Python, Rails, Ruby, SQL, Kotlin, Git, Redmine, MariaDB, Gitlab, Jira, Bitbucket, Mattermost, Docker, Jenkins CI,", 
    "Trello, Asana, Microsoft Office, Photoshop, Unity 3D,", 
    "Java, CMS, Scrum, C++, SOA, EDA, Cloud,", "SQL, Adobe, Python, SQL, ABAP, React + TypeScript, Node.js, CMS, REST API, Tensorflow + Pytorch, Flutter, AWS Deployment, SAP, Jira, AutoCAD", 
    NA), Job1_latest = c("Senior Engineer - Machine learning", 
    "Senior Machine Learning Engineer", "Application Developer Associate Manager", 
    "Senior Data & ML  Engineer", "Senior Machine Learning Engineer", 
    "Software Developer", "Machine Learning Engineer", "Akademischer  Mitarbeiter, Machine  Learning  and Analytics", 
    "Senior Backend Developer", "Senior Web Developer", "Software Architect / Development lead", 
    NA, "Data Analysing (Researcher)", "Software Engineer", "Sofware Developer", 
    "Senior Associate Experience Technology", "Senior Software Architect", 
    "Senior Software Developer / Tech Lead", "Fullstack Developer/ ProductOwner", 
    "Freelancing Software Developer", "Senior Software Developer / Teamlead", 
    "Fullstack JavaScript Developer", "Blowoutandgo Application Developer", 
    "Software Developer", "Software Engineer", "Senior Frontend Engineer and Lead Developer", 
    "Javascript Developer", "Data  Scientist/ Python Developer", 
    "Research Assistant", "Fullstack Engineer", "Backend Developer", 
    "App-Backend Developer", "Senior Software Developer", "Android Developer", 
    "Android Software Engineer", "Senior Android Developer", 
    "Senior C# Developer", "Software Developer", "Applications Developer", 
    "Senior Android Developer", "Android Developer", "Senior Android Engineer", 
    "Mobile Engineer", "Senior Android Developer", "Software Engineer", 
    "Senior UX/UI Designer", "User Experience Designer", "Design Consultant", 
    "Frontend Product Designer", "Team Lead Payment Page and Processing", 
    "Head of Engineering", "Senior Software Engineering Manager", 
    "Head of Technology", "Head of Development", "Senior Software Developer", 
    "Producer", "Vice President", "Software Developer", NA), 
    Years1 = c(3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, 1, 4, 
    1, 6, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 
    2, NA, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 
    2, 2, 6, 1, 2, NA), Job2 = c("Data Scientist", "Machine Learning Engineer", 
    "Machine Learning Developer - Associate Manager", "Senior DWH&BI Engineer", 
    "Co-Founder & CTO", "Software Developer", "Data Engineer", 
    "Application Software Engineer", "Backend Develope", "Lead PHP Developer", 
    "Lead PHP developer", NA, "Machine Learning Engineer", "Software Engineer", 
    "Expert Application Development Specialist", "SDE 3", "Developer Trainer & Mentor", 
    "Senior Software Developer", "Senior Software Developer", 
    "AI Developer", "Software Developer & Consulatance", "Web & Communication Consultance", 
    "Mobile Application Development", "Frontend Developer", "Web Developer", 
    "Fullstack Engineer", "Javascript Developer", "Junior Research Scientist", 
    "Junior Data Analyst", "Frontend Engineer", "Senior Software Developer", 
    "Fullstack Developer", "Senior Software Developer", "Android Developer", 
    "Android Software Engineer", "Mobile Application Developer", 
    "Senior Java Developer", "Android Developer", "Android Developer", 
    "Mobile Application Developer", "Mobile Developer", "Senior Android Engineer", 
    "Senior Android Developer", "Senior Android Developer", "Software Engineer", 
    "UI/UX Designer", "Senior Information Technology Consultant", 
    "Global Head of Design", "Lead Product Desiger", "Product Manager / Product Analyst", 
    "Lead DevOps Engineer", "Vice President Tech", "Head of Product", 
    "IT Lead", "Android Consultant", "Social Game Designer", 
    "Head of Enterprise Architecture", "Team Supervisor", NA), 
    Years2 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 3, 1, 8, 2, NA, 2, 2, 1, 
    2, 8, 1, 1, 1, 6, 4, 2, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 1, 1, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 3, 6, 3, 1, 1, 1, 
    2, 2, 2, 5, 1, NA), Job3 = c("Senior Research Scientist", 
    "Senior Analytics Analyst", "Senior Developer", NA, "Graduate Research Assistant", 
    "Software Developer", NA, NA, "Software Developer", "Senior Web Developer", 
    "Lead PHP/SugarCRM developer", NA, "Data Engineer", "Software Engineer", 
    "Senior Application Development Specialist", "Manager L1 (UI/ Frontend)", 
    "Application Infrastructor Lead", "Software Developer", "Software Developer & Consultance", 
    "Software Developer", "Student Assistant", NA, "HEB Retail Application", 
    NA, NA, "Senior Software Engineer", "Frontend Web Developer", 
    "Computational Scientist/ Backend Developer", NA, "Fullstack Engineer", 
    "IT Specialist - Application Developer", "Insurance Software Programmer", 
    "Software Developer", "Android Developer", NA, "Software Developer", 
    "Senior C# Developer", "Embedded Software Intern", "Android Developer", 
    "Android Developer", "Java Developer", "Senior Android Engineer", 
    NA, "Techlead of Mobile Development Group", "Software Engineer", 
    "Product Designer", "User Experience Designer", "Chief UX and Product Architect", 
    "Product Designer UI/UX & Motion", "Senior Web Developer", 
    "Lead Developer", "Senior Manager Digital Platform Development", 
    "Head of Engineering", "IT Manager", "Head of Software Development", 
    "QA Tester", "Head of Enterprise Archticture, Lead of EA & Innovation", 
    "Videography Consultant", NA), Years3 = c(1, 1, 5, NA, 2, 
    1, NA, NA, 2, 3, 2, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, 7, 2, 2, 5, 1, NA, 2, 
    NA, NA, 1, 1, 4, NA, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 
    2, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, NA), 
    Job4 = c("Research Scientist", "Analytics Analyst", "Optical Engineer", 
    NA, "Graduate Teaching Assistant", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "PHP/ZEND Developer", 
    NA, "Software Engineer", NA, "Senior Application Development Specialist Consultance", 
    "Senior Engineer- Technology", "Fullstack IOS Developer", 
    "Software Engineering Manager/ Solution Architect", "Senior Software Developer", 
    "Software Developer", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Frontend Engineer and Teamlead Frontend", 
    "Forensic Principal Expert at Special Technical Department", 
    NA, NA, "Fullstack Engineer", "Java Web Developer", "Perl & Oracle Programmer", 
    "Software Engineering Manager", NA, NA, NA, "Senior Web Developer", 
    NA, NA, "Software Developer", "Android Developer", "Senior Android Engineer/Team Lead", 
    NA, "Android/iOS App Developer", "Software Engineer", "Art Director, Lead UX/UI Designer", 
    "Founder & CEO", "Director, User Experience", "Senior Product Designer UI/UX & Motion", 
    "Senior Consultant/ Senior Software Engineer", "CTO & Partner", 
    "Senior Consutant/ Architect", NA, "Managing Director IT", 
    "Android Developer", NA, "Enterprise Architect", "Software Modification Consultant", 
    NA), Years4 = c(5, 2, 3, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, 
    2, NA, 6, 1, 9, 2, 8, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 1, NA, NA, 
    1, 1, 3, 2, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, 1, 1, 4, NA, 1, 2, 2, 
    2, 1, 5, 3, 2, 2, NA, 2, 4, NA, 1, 2, NA), Job5 = c("PhD fellow", 
    "Java developer Intern", NA, NA, "Senior Software Engineer", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "PHP System Analytic / Software specialist", 
    NA, NA, NA, "Application Developer Consultance", "Frontend Engineer", 
    NA, "Technical Delivery Manager", "Application Developer", 
    "Software Developer", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Web Designer/ Developer", 
    NA, NA, NA, "Java Software Developer", "Java Junior Programmer", 
    "Technical Delivery Manager", NA, NA, NA, "Senior Mobile Developer", 
    NA, NA, "Software Developer Intern", "Technical Consultant", 
    "Software Engineer", NA, "Fullstack Android Developer", "Software Engineer", 
    "Senior Designer", "CEO, PR & Marketing", "Managing Partner/ User Experience", 
    "Art Director", "Software Entwickler", "Developer & Consultant", 
    "Extern Senior Java Developer", NA, "Vice President Solution Delivery", 
    "Development & Sales", NA, "Senior Architect E-Commerce", 
    "IT & Custom Computer Service", NA), Years5 = c(3, 1, NA, 
    NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 2, 2, 
    2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 5, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 2, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, NA, 
    4, 2, NA, 1, 3, NA), Job6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "Web Developer", NA, NA, NA, "Software Instrocture", 
    "Associate Software Engineer", NA, "Software Engineer", "Software Architect", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Software Engineer", 
    NA, NA, NA, "Senior Web Developer", NA, NA, NA, "Software Engineer", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Regional Head of Experience", NA, 
    NA, "Junior IT Security Analyst", "Feelance Consulant", NA, 
    "Senior Software Engineer", NA, NA, "Team Lead E-Commerce", 
    NA, NA), Years6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    2, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, NA, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 2, NA, 1, NA, NA, 4, 
    NA, NA), Job7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "Assistant Network Administrator", NA, NA, 
    "Technical Delivery Manager/ Project Manager", NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    "Senior Mobile Developer", NA, NA, NA, "Web Developer", NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Developement Lead", 
    NA, "Chief Software Architect", NA, NA, "Senior Software Developer", 
    NA, NA), Years7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
    3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10, NA, 1, NA, 
    NA, 3, NA, NA), Job8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Trainee ES Computer", NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "Big-Data Developer", NA, NA, NA, "Supervisor Support", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Product Development", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Years8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
    NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Job9 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "Fullstack Developer", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Software Architecture", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Years9 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Job10 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "Senior Software Developer", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), Years10 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), Job11 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    "Software Developer", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Years11 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Job12 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "IT/ Organisation", NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), Years12 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), problems = structure(list(row = c(13L, 
24L, 36L), col = c("Years1", "Years2", "Years1"), expected = c("no trailing characters", 
"no trailing characters", "no trailing characters"), actual = c("0,2", 
"0,6", "0,4"), file = c("'Recruitee Tech CVs - Tabellenblatt1 (1).csv'", 
"'Recruitee Tech CVs - Tabellenblatt1 (1).csv'", "'Recruitee Tech CVs - Tabellenblatt1 (1).csv'"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-59L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Index = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), FromJob = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Highest_education_achieved = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Skills = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Job1_latest = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Years1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Job2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Years2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Job3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Years3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Job4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Years4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Job5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Years5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Job6 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Years6 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Job7 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Years7 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Job8 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Years8 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Job9 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Years9 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Job10 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Years10 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Job11 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Years11 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Job12 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Years12 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value which is next to last non-NA value.

```
first_job <- function(x)   {x1 <- x[!is.na(x)];x1[length(x1) - 1][1]}
apply(data[-(1:4)], 1, first_job)

#[1] "PhD fellow"               "Java developer Intern"    "Optical Engineer" 
#[4] "Senior DWH&BI Engineer"   "Senior Software Engineer" "Software Developer"
```

Comment: thank you! When using the proposed code I'm getting e.g. [[54]]
             Job12 
"IT/ Organisation" instead of just the job titles like you did, is there a way to only get the job titles for each line?

Comment: That's strange. Do you mean you are using the code in my answer on the same data that you shared and getting different output?

Comment: I created the data for you using dput(head(data)) because the real data is too long for posting here, if I insert the data I posted here and your code it works but ut doesn't with the real long data

Comment: Can you provide part of the dataset which returns incorrect result so that I can check for it sepcifically.

Comment: I managed to insert the whole dput(data) in my question now! Maybe it's the NAs that cause the problem?

Comment: I think it is because in certain rows there are no non-NA values in them. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

This `tidyverse` approach will also do

```
df %>% select(1:4, starts_with('Job')) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with('Job'), values_drop_na = T) %>%
  group_by(Index) %>%
  slice_tail()


# A tibble: 57 x 6
# Groups:   Index [57]
   Index FromJob          Highest_education_achiev~ Skills                                     name  value        
   <dbl> <chr>            <chr>                     <chr>                                      <chr> <chr>        
 1     1 Senior Machine ~ PhD                       "Machine Learning, Mathematical Modeling,~ Job5  PhD fellow   
 2     2 Senior Machine ~ MSc Computer Science      "Java, AngularJS, frontend, backend, Azur~ Job5  Java develop~
 3     3 Senior Machine ~ MSc                       "Biometrics, Machine Learning, Pattern Re~ Job4  Optical Engi~
 4     4 Senior Machine ~ MBA                       "Databricks, Spark, Airflow, AWS Sagemake~ Job2  Senior DWH&B~
 5     5 Senior Machine ~ MSc                       "Spark, Tensorflow &TFX, Kubeflow, BigQue~ Job5  Senior Softw~
 6     6 Python Data Eng~ MSc                       "PythonC++, C, OpenCV, OpenCL, MatLab, Te~ Job3  Software Dev~
 7     7 Python Data Eng~ MSc                       "Microsoft SQL Server, Hadoop,SQL Server ~ Job2  Data Engineer
 8     8 Python Data Eng~ MSc Communication and Me~ "Keras, TensorFlow, scikit-learn, NLTK, O~ Job2  Application ~
 9     9 Lead Backend De~ High School               "ElasticSearch, OOP, NoSQL, SQL, Docker, ~ Job3  Software Dev~
10    10 Lead Backend De~ BSc Informatics           "PHP, Java Script, CSS, (X)HTML, MySQL., ~ Job3  Senior Web D~
# ... with 47 more rows
```

---

More generally, if you want filter nth job (your job nos are actually reversed) you may do something like this

```r
#Ex for 2nd job

df %>% select(1:4, starts_with('Job')) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with('Job'), values_drop_na = T) %>%
  group_by(Index) %>%
  filter(rev(row_number()) == 2)
#> # A tibble: 57 x 6
#> # Groups:   Index [57]
#>    Index FromJob     Highest_education_a~ Skills             name  value        
#>    <dbl> <chr>       <chr>                <chr>              <chr> <chr>        
#>  1     1 Senior Mac~ PhD                  "Machine Learning~ Job4  Research Sci~
#>  2     2 Senior Mac~ MSc Computer Science "Java, AngularJS,~ Job4  Analytics An~
#>  3     3 Senior Mac~ MSc                  "Biometrics, Mach~ Job3  Senior Devel~
#>  4     4 Senior Mac~ MBA                  "Databricks, Spar~ Job1~ Senior Data ~
#>  5     5 Senior Mac~ MSc                  "Spark, Tensorflo~ Job4  Graduate Tea~
#>  6     6 Python Dat~ MSc                  "PythonC++, C, Op~ Job2  Software Dev~
#>  7     7 Python Dat~ MSc                  "Microsoft SQL Se~ Job1~ Machine Lear~
#>  8     8 Python Dat~ MSc Communication a~ "Keras, TensorFlo~ Job1~ Akademischer~
#>  9     9 Lead Backe~ High School          "ElasticSearch, O~ Job2  Backend Deve~
#> 10    10 Lead Backe~ BSc Informatics      "PHP, Java Script~ Job2  Lead PHP Dev~
#> # ... with 47 more rows
```

---

Optionally you may also do

```
df %>% select(1:4, starts_with('Job')) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with('Job'), values_drop_na = T) %>%
  group_by(Index) %>%
  slice(n() -1)
```

Comment: Thank you @AnilGoyal !  Do you know how I can change the code to get the 4th last value of each row?

Comment: What is meant by 4th last? Do you mean fourth job?

Comment: Using the code you provided I am getting the last job from each person which is the second last value in each line. Now I want to get the second last job of each person which is the 4th last value per row (there is always the job name and in the next column the years in that job)

Comment: See edited answer.  For second job from last you may use the code above.  For similar other values replace `2` by desired `n`th value.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in python?